# Upload laravel 5 project to share hosting

Tags: php, laravel

im newbie with laravel. i have problems when uploading my laravel project to my shared hosting.

when i go into my domain.com/laravel/public/ , i cant see anything. they return it with blank page. no error at all. i dont understand.

i try to follow all instructions in internet, but all i got is nothing.

i change index.php inside of public folder.
from this :

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

into :

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

i also modify my .htaccess file into

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^awesome-project
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ awesome-project/$1 [L]
```

but still all i got is blank page.
what can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: When you upload the project, before the changes, does `domain.com/laravel/public` work fine?

Comment: I think you might be having trouble getting into db. try log into mysql on command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running Apache2? Check your site conf file and make sure the document root is pointed to the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

you should be getting a 404 error if path is incorrect. A white page with a new Laravel installation usually means you need to check the permissions of your storage folders.

From the Laravel 5 documentation:
"Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server"

Answer (score 0):

You should restore your Laravel files to original state, then you must set your host to a `laravel/public` directory. It will work only if you'll do both steps.

If you have trouble with setting up your web server, you can find an instruction for Apache here:
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Also, don't forget to restart your web server after doing all the changes.

Comment: what do you mean with restore to original state? i dont have any permission to restart the web server from my hosting provider.

Comment: You said you made some changes in .htaccess and index.php, just use original files. Try to point web server to a public directory and maybe it will work without restarting. If not, contact support and tell them you'd like to restart apache, I think they will do that for you.